# Undefined class 'TapDownInfo' in flutter/flame

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

The games/animation package "flame" for flutter has a couple of tutorials, the second of which ([link](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/main/tutorials/2_sprite_animations_gestures/code/lib/main.dart)) does not compile due to `Undefined class 'TapDownInfo'`.

What include do I need for this, or is relating to an earlier version of the flutter SDK? (currently `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"` with `flame: ^1.0.0-rc9` )

```
@override
void onTapDown(TapDownInfo event) {
  final buttonArea = buttonPosition & buttonSize;
  isPressed = buttonArea.contains(event.eventPosition.game.toOffset());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial doesn't exist for `rc9`, if you want tutorials specific to a version you have to look at that tag in git. For example:
https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/tree/1.0.0-rc9/tutorials

You can also clone the flame repository if you want to run that tutorial, or depend on the `main` branch instead of `rc9`.

We will most likely release `rc10` today or tomorrow and in there that tutorial will be included.

Here is how you can depend on `main` in your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  flame:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flame-engine/flame.git
      path: packages/flame
      ref: main
```

EDIT: `1.4.0` has now been released so you can use the tutorial directly with that version.

Answer (score 0):

For the `1.0.0-rc10`. (I agreed that the good doc (For the latest version) is sometime harder to find until the true release).

For your question, it depends if you talk about your main gameComponent (the one `extends BaseGame`) and if you have the `with HasTapableComponents` or not.

On the if its your `mainGame extends BaseGame with HasTapableComponents`, it should be override like that:

```dart
  @override
  bool onTapDown(int pointerId, TapDownDetails details) {
    super.onTapDown(pointerId, details);
    // Your code
    return true;
  }
```

On others sub component it like that: `ExitButton extends PositionComponent with Tapable`, it should look pretty the same without the `pointerId`.

```dart
  @override
  bool onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
    super.onTapDown(details);
    // Your code
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using flame 1.0.0. You'll have to import appropriate library/class/module. It can be confusing because documentation is not good. I was also facing similar problem. I figured out that if I just type the name of the "undefined" class in the android studio, it'll show the class/module it belongs to. For me the following code doesn't throw any "undefined" class error!

```
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/input.dart';

class TappableComponent extends PositionComponent with Tappable {

// update and render omitted

 @override
 bool onTapUp(TapUpInfo info) {
 print("tap up");
 return true;
 }

 @override
 bool onTapDown(TapDownInfo info) {
 print("tap down");
 return true;
 }

 @override
 bool onTapCancel() {
 print("tap cancel");
 return true;
 }
}
```